Convergence in distribution $\sum(X_iX_j)/\sum({X_i}^2)$
Let $X_i$ be iid with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Prove that the following sequence converges in distribution and find the limit:
$$
\frac{\sum_{j\neq i}^nX_iX_j}{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}
$$
My idea was to write this as $\frac{\sum_{j\neq i}^nX_iX_j}{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2} = \frac{(\sum X_i)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2} - 1 = \left(\frac{\sum X_i}{n}\right)^2\frac{n^2}{\sum X_i^2} - 1$
Since $\frac{\sum X_i}{n}\stackrel{a.s.}{\rightarrow}0$ then if I prove that $\frac{n^2}{\sum X_i^2}$ converges, then the whole thing will converge to $-1$. But proving this seems hard to me.
If I instead would write $\frac{\sum_{j\neq i}^nX_iX_j}{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2} = \frac{(\sum X_i)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2} - 1 = \left(\frac{\sum X_i}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\frac{n}{\sum X_i^2} - 1$
then I would be done if I could say that $\left(\frac{\sum X_i}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2$ converges to anything. So is there any theorem that says: if $Y_n\stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{\rightarrow}\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then $Y_n^2\stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{\rightarrow}something$ ?

$\frac{n^2}{\sum X_i^2} \to \infty$ with probability $1$.

You are almost there.
Write \begin{align}\frac{\sum_{j\neq i}^nX_iX_j}{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}
&=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2}{\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2} - 1\\&=\frac{Z_n^2}{S_n}-1.
\end{align}
Then use weak law of large numbers to establish $S_n\overset{\mathbb P}{\to}\mathbb E(X_1^2)=1$. Use central limit theorem to establish that the sequence $Z_n$ converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable $Z$. Thus, by continuous mapping theorem we get $Z_n^2\overset{\mathrm d}{\to}Z^2$, which is a $\chi^2(1)$-distributed random variable.
Then use Slutzky theorem to conclude that $$\frac{Z_n^2}{S_n}\overset{\mathrm d}{\to}Z^2.$$ Finally, we get
$$\frac{Z_n^2}{S_n}-1\overset{\mathrm d}{\to}Z^2-1.$$ Thus, the asymptotic distribution of our sequence is the chi-squared distribution $\chi^2(1)$ shifted by 1.

Yes there is such a result, the continuous mapping theorem! See for example here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem
